# Passing an array from shortcode-function to filter-function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters

This might be a php question more than it is a wordpress question. I am not sure though, but please guide me if so. I am working on a trial plugin that I use for my training in the first stages of plugin development.

Here is a simplified example of the structure:

```
class trial{

    function trial() {
        add_shortcode( 'shs_ref', array( &$this, 'shortcode' ) );
        add_filter( 'the_content', array( &$this, 'after_content' ));
    }

    /*Run the shortcode*/
    function shortcode( $atts , $content = null ) {

        if ( !isset( $this->entries ) )
            $this->entries = array();

        array_push($this->entries,$content);

        return 'What number of shortcode is this: ',count($this->entries);

    }

    /*Add after the page content*/
    function after_content( $content ) {

        foreach($this->entries as $entry) /*This one is empty?*/
           $content .= $entry;

        return $content;
    }

}

new trial();
```

In the `shortcode` function, an array `$this->entries` is being filled with the content `$content` that the user has wrapped inside the shortcode clamps. For every new occasion of the shortcode, its content is appended to the array via php's `array_push`. I can then do something with this growing array `$this->entries` (for example count its contents, as in the example).

All this is fine and works.

The issue comes when I want a *filter*-function to use that same array. I want a list of all the collected shortcode contents to be added at the bottom of the page. At the top of the code, I use an `add_filter` which passes `the_content` to my other function called `after_content`. This works and the entire page content can be handled by the function. But the `$this->entries` array is empty. It kept its content while being used iteratively in the `shortcode` function, but it loses its content when it is used in the `after_content` function afterwards.

I have tried setting the `$this->entries` array as a global variable, for instance by adding `var $stored_entries` outside the function and then `global $stored_entries; $stored_entries = $this->entries` inside the shortcode-function, but it makes no difference. The content of `$this->entries` as well as  `$stored_entries` is `NULL`.

The question is mainly:

- **How can I pass the array on to this other function?**

And secondarily:

- **Why is that array stored between iterations of the shortcode-function but forgotten when we enter the filter-function?**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out that I was missing a tiny little number in the `add_filter` command. The line:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array( &$this, 'after_content' ));
```

should be:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', array( &$this, 'after_content' ), 12);
```

And now all works. The array is accessible inside the filter-function. This number is a priority variable: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/, but if anyone will add a comment on the usefulness of it, please do so.